# Generic memoize function returning the same function type

Tags: typescript, memoization

I am trying to write a memoize function that takes a function as an argument and returns an alike memoized function.

```
function memoize<T extends Function, R>(f: T): T {
  const memory = new Map<string, R>();

  const g = (...args: any[]) => {
    if (!memory.get(args.join())) { memory.set(args.join(), f(...args)); }
    return memory.get(args.join());
  };

  return g; // g as T => [ts] Type '(...args: any[]) => R' cannot be converted to type 'T'.
}

// const exp: (...args: any[]) => RegExp
const exp = memoize<(text: string) => RegExp, RegExp>((text: string) => {
  return new RegExp(text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, ".").replace(/\s+/g, "\\s+"), "ig");
});
```

The problem is that if I just return `g` , the signature of exp becomes `(...args: any[]) => RexExp` and if I try to force g to be T, then `ts` complains that g is not assignable to `T`.

Is there a way to "force" `g` to be the same type of `f` in order to `exp` to have the exact same type of the function passed to `memoize`?

Comment: `args.join()` is no good as a key: you have a problem for functions that take objects because, for example, both `[{}].join()` and `[{foo: 'bar'}].join()` return the same value: `"[object Object]"`. Using just `args` as a map key is no better though because map uses strict equality, so the 'non-strict-equal' values would be memoized multiple times.

Comment: @artem Thanks for the comments. You are right, that is not a good key. It looks like building a tree using maps would be a better solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
function memoize<R, T extends (...args: any[]) => R>(f: T): T {
    const memory = new Map<string, R>();

    const g = (...args: any[]) => {
        if (!memory.get(args.join())) {
            memory.set(args.join(), f(...args));
        }

        return memory.get(args.join());
    };

    return g as T;
}

const exp = memoize((text: string) => {
    return new RegExp(text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, ".").replace(/\s+/g, "\\s+"), "ig");
});
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20memoize%3CR%2C%20T%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20R%3E(f%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20memory%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20R%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20g%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!memory.get(args.join()))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20memory.set(args.join()%2C%20f(...args))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memory.get(args.join())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20g%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20exp%20%3D%20memoize((text%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20RegExp(text.replace(%2F%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%5Cs%5D%2Fg%2C%20%22.%22).replace(%2F%5Cs%2B%2Fg%2C%20%22%5C%5Cs%2B%22)%2C%20%22ig%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B))